# Pandas DataFrame filtering of groups of rows on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Here's a simplified version of my dataframe:

```
d = {'col1': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3'], 'col2': [1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'col3': [-1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   a1       1      -1
1   a2       1      -1
2   a3       1       1
3   b1      -1      -1
4   b2      -1      -1
5   b3      -1       1
6   c1      -1       1
7   c2       1       1
8   c3       1       1
9   d1      -1      -1
10  d2       1      -1
11  d3       1       1
```

i would like to be able to pull out only those rows where `col3 == 1` **for the first time** `n` rows after `col2 == 1` **for the first time**, for each letter group.

so for example, if we're looking for when col3 became 1 *one row* after col2 became 1 (for each letter group), we'll get

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   d3      1       1
```

because for group **d** col2 turned from -1 to 1 at d2 and col3 turned from -1 to 1 at d3. And that hasn't happened in any other group.

if we want rows where col3 became 1 *two rows* after col2 became 1 (for each letter group), we'll get

```
    col1    col2    col3
0   a3      1       1
```

because for group **a** col2 started with 1 at a1 and col3 turned from -1 to 1 at a3.

Edit:

Here's my awkward way of doing it ... anyone got more elegant solutions?

```
df['newCol'] = (
           (((df['col2'].shift(n+1).isnull() | (df['col2'].shift(n+1) == -1)) &
           (df['col2'].shift(n+1).isnull() | (df['col2'].shift(n+1) == -1))) |
           (df['col1'].shift(n+1).str[0] != df['col1'].str[0])) &
           (df['col2'].shift(n) == 1) &
           (df['col3'].shift(n) == -1) &
           (df['col2'].shift(1) == 1) &
           (df['col3'].shift(1) == -1) &
           (df['col2'] == 1) &
           (df['col3'] == 1) &
           (df['col1'].shift(n).str[0] == df['col1'].str[0])) if n > 0 \
            else \
           ((((df['col2'].shift(n+1).isnull() | (df['col2'].shift(n+1) == -1)) &
           (df['col2'].shift(n+1).isnull() | (df['col2'].shift(n+1) == -1))) |
           (df['col1'].shift(n+1).str[0] != df['col1'].str[0])) &
           (df['col2'] == 1) &
           (df['col3'] == 1))
```

Comment: *col1* is your label, do you mean *after **col2** beame 1*?

Comment: @QuangHoang sorry, yes, just fixed it

Comment: I would recommend reading some of the Pandas documentation on how to filter on dataframes. You'll be able to answer this relatively quickly.

Comment: @mrp i know how to do basic filtering. This however I have found to be a challenge.

Comment: You can accomplish this by using a loop where you'll save the index when the conditions are met.

Comment: @mrp yep, that's exactly what i'm working on now. We'll see how it goes

Comment: A perhaps more performant way would be to create a new column that is a lag of the conditional column using `shift()`.  So then you can filter using pandas standard filters on arrays, which will be faster if your dataframe is very large.

Answer (score 1):

To put my last comment into an answer.  Create a new column that is a lag using `n`, then just filter the standard way and grab the first value of `col1`.

```
n = 2
df['newCol'] = df['col2'].shift(n)
df.loc[(df['col3'] == 1) & (df['newCol'] == 1), ['col1']].values[0]
```

You can wrap this into a function and make everything parameters.

Comment: ----- Edit nm, i was trying to just get the rows, and forgot the values[0] part... I guess i'd need to convert array back to dataframe afterwards?
-----

Close, but not quite.
Try this:
d = {'col1': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'b3', 'b4', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'd1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'],'col2': [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],'col3': [-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, 1, 1, 1]}.
That should only be a3, but it comes back with a3, a4, c4, d2, d3, d4.

Comment: lemme mess with it more, i still feel like it's not doing it exactly >.<

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
n=2
cond = pd.concat([(df['col2'] == 1).groupby(df['col1'].str[0]).cumsum().shift(n),
                  (df['col3'] == 1).groupby(df['col1'].str[0]).cumsum()], 
                 axis=1)\
         .eq(1)\
         .all(axis=1)
df[cond]
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  col3
2   a3     1     1
```

Or more simply I think:

```
cond1 = (df['col2'] == 1).groupby(df['col1'].str[0]).cumsum().shift(n) == 1
cond2 = (df['col3'] == 1).groupby(df['col1'].str[0]).cumsum() == 1
df[cond1 & cond2]
```

Comment: First script almost works, but n=3 still returns d2 where it shouldn't return anything. Second script doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: @Raksa when I run n=3 I am getting empty dataframes.  Anyway, I think this is an approach you can troubleshoot with your data.